# Annihilator property dual

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras, fourier-transform

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $\phi$ be in $ L^{\infty}(G)$ that annihilates $I$, where $I$ is a closed ideal of $ L^1(G)$, so by duality we have:
$$\int_G f(y)\phi(y)dy=0$$ 
for all $f\in I$.

$\mathbf{QUESTION}$:  Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group. Is it true that if $\phi$ annihilates $I$, then $\int_G f(-y)\phi(y)dy=0$ for all $f\in I$? Is the convers true?

Comment: If $\phi$ annihilates $L^1(G)$, then $\phi$ is zero itself.

Comment: Thanks you prof. Corbennik for your comment. You are right. Infact $\phi$ annihilates $I\subset L^1(G)$.

Comment: Oh shucks, I misread the question. Well for that one you may choose an open set $U$ and let $I$ be the ideal of all $f$ that vanish on $U$. Then $\phi$ must simply vanish on $U$, but not on $-U$.

Comment: The comments on your previous question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266727/  seemed to indicate that Rudin is defining the duality pairing between $L^1(G)$ and $L^\infty(G)$ in a way **different from** the one you use at the start of your question. Hence I don't understand the motivation for your actual question

Answer (score 1):

Really, I prove that if $f\in I$, then $\check{f}\in I$ where $I$ is a closed ideal of $L^1(G)$ and $\check{f}(x)=f(x^{-1})$ for every unimodular group $G$. Therefore since $\phi$ annihilate $I$. so 
$$\int f(y^{-1})\phi(y)dy=0$$